# How to load image inside the UIImageView created using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder

I created an UIImageView using xib. When I used the following codes, the image appears on the top left hand corner on the simulator. Although I have set the bottom constraint of the UIImageView to be 45 above the black button using the Interface Builder, it didn't work.

I would like the image to show at the location where I placed the UIImageView using xib. Please help! Thanks!

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"];
self.imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.imageHolder.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:self.imageHolder];
```

[image: UIImageView]

Comment: Create an IBOutlet for your image view and load the image into that instance and not create a new instance altogether. Right now from what I can see from your code, your xib image view is untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the way you described, you're initialising two UIImageViews: one in your XIB and one in code. You don't need these lines:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"];
self.imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.imageHolder.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:self.imageHolder];
```

Just create an IBOutlet property of your UIImageView to the corresponding view controller like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

The property doesn't need any initialisation. Just put this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"];
```

If the image won't be set dynamically, set it in your XIB at the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

IOS will automatically look for your file "overflow.png" in the same bundle as your xib file. If your xib file is just in your application's target, then by default it looks inside the main bundle.

If you want to programatically load a new image into an image view and your image is inside the main bundle:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyAwesomeImage"];
self.imageView = image;
```

If your image is inside another bundle:

```
NSBundle *imageBundle = ...   // [NSBundle mainBundle] if your image is    inside main bundle
NSString *imagePath = [imageBundle pathForResource:@"MyAwesomeImage"    ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

First click on the "show the assistant editor button to both show interface builder & code

Then **click+ctrl button**  and drag Image to code to create an IBOutlet.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *sunImage;
```

Then in  `-(void)viewdidload` or where you would like to set image

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.jpg"];
[self.sunImage setImage:image];
```